# Assigning strings to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the below string which will be given as the input to a function.

> 01 02 01 **0D A1 D6 72 02 00** 01 00 00 00 00 53 73 F2

The highlighted part is the address I need.

If the preceding byte is 1 then I have to take only 6 octet and assign it to a variable.

If it is more than 1 the I should read 6 * Num(preceding value) and assign 6 octets for each variable.

Currently I am assigning it statically.

```
def main(line_input):
    Device = ' '.join(line_input[9:3:-1])
    Length = line_input[2]
    var1 = line_input[3]
main("01 02 02 0D A1 D6 72 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 53 73 F2")
```

Can this be done?

Comment: how do you determine the address you need? is it always from the 4th octet onwards?

Comment: Preceding byte equal 1 is also before the second octet, so why did you start from the fourth?

Comment: Do you want to keep working with string or do you want to convert it to an integer ?
unhexlify may help you

Comment: @dhdavvie address always strats from 4th octet.

Comment: @Julien Either way will work.

Comment: Im trying to do a correct answer but it's not easy. Have you a reason to use python2 instead python3 ? Python3 is much more intuitive with strings

Comment: @Julien I have to use python 2 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I think this does it, let me know if there is anything that needs changing:

```
import string 

def address_extract(line_input):
    line_input = string.split(line_input, ' ')
    length = 6 * int(line_input[2]) 
    device_list = []
    for x in range(3, 3+length, 6):
        if x+6 > len(line_input):
            print "Length multiplier too long for input string"
        else:
            device_list.append(' '.join(line_input[x:x+6]))

    return device_list

print address_extract("01 02 02 0D A1 D6 72 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 53 73 F2")
#output = ['0D A1 D6 72 02 00', '01 00 00 00 00 53']
```

Comment: What will happen if the line_input[2] is 1.

Comment: it will print `['0D A1 D6 72 02 00']`. Then you can simply use a for loop to print all the addresses individually or whatever you want to do with them

Comment: it helps a lot. But i have one more query. After the address if some other hex digit i get(say some additional info about the Device) how can i process that with this code. Say next bytes are 1 octet ot 2 octet.

Comment: thats something you need to know. You need to know how big the set of data you are trying to extract. If there are 2 more pieces of info after the address, then you need to change the length to be multiplied by 8, since now the data you want is 8 octets long. You would need to increase the step count in the for loop to 8, and the length check. Then x+7 and x+8 will access those 2 octets after the 6 octet address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I hope will help you. I tried to add many comments to explain what is happening

```
import binascii
import struct

#note python 3 behaves differently and won't work with this code (personnaly I find it easyer for strings convertion to bytes)
def main(line_input):
    formated_line = line_input.split(" ") #I start by cutting the input on each space character
    print formated_line #the output is a list. Each element is composed of 2 chars
    formated_line = [binascii.unhexlify(xx) for xx in formated_line] #create a list composed of unhelified bytes of each elements of the original list
    print formated_line #the output is a list of bytes char
    #can be done in one step but I try to be clearer as you are nee to python (moereover this is easyer in python-3.x)
    formated_line = map(ord, formated_line) #convert to a list of int (this is not needed in python 3)
    print formated_line
    Length = formated_line[2] #this is an int
    unformated_var1 = formated_line[3:3+(6*length)] #keep only interesting data
    #now you can format your address

main("01 02 02 0D A1 D6 72 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 53 73 F2")
#if the input comes from a machine and not a human, they could exchange 17bytes instead of (17x3)characters
#main("\x01\x02\x02\x0D\xA1\xD6\x72\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x53\x73\xF2")
#then the parsing could be done with struct.unpack
```

Comment: Thanks it also helps.